# Anime: 2 girls at a cafe, gem falls into one of their drinks

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can't remember this anime I watched. All I know is there were 2 girls sitting at cafe and a bunch of guys came out of the sky, they were after a gem that fell into one of the girls' drinks. The gem was really important so they had to protect the girl that had the gem inside her because she had drank it. By the way I was watching the dubbed version.

I forgot why the guys were after the gem but there were also bad people trying to take the gem. I remember in the 1st episode the girl who swallowed the gem got kidnapped because the gem was inside her.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Is this **[Save Me! Lollipop](https://aminoapps.com/c/anime/page/item/save-me-lollipop/X1tX_IgmXWb0zrbkBm325ab5d3gbRm)**?

> Nina Yamada is your normal, typical, ordinary girl who dreams of finding her Prince Charming one day! Well that day may come sooner then she thinks. One day she’s out with her friends at a cake shop when a magical pink gem falls from the sky onto her plate. She mistakes it for candy and eats it only to find out after a hoard of people also come flying from the sky to get the gem back.